# Is there a suggested plot for a multivariate normal sample?

Tags: python, histogram

I just signed up on Stack Overflow! I'm kinda figuring out how to plot a multivariate Gaussian distribution, given a null mean vector and a covariance matrix.

What I've tried to do is a histogram but it says not so much about the sample. I read an NxM table from a CSV and plot it:

```
def plot_gaussian_sample(csv):
df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None)

data = df.values.reshape(30000,1);

# Fit a normal distribution to the data:
mu, std = 0,1 #norm.fit(df[0])

# Plot the histogram.
plt.hist(data, bins=100, density=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')

# Plot the PDF.
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekFhr.png)

What would it be a good way to represent it?

I hope this is the right spot to post such a question :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. However, it's not a good place to ask this question because you're asking for opinions; you don't have a particular issue with your code itself.

Comment: Oh, what I can do to improve the questions? Should I delete it? @roganjosh

Comment: I'm not telling you to delete it, but you may be able to frame the question differently. "I tried this code <xyz> and it screwed up the x-axis labels" would be more along the lines of questions here. If you've tried something and it didn't work out, then that might be a good topic